# Fast algorithm for compacting a buffer

Tags: opencl

I am performing image compression.

The image *I* is broken up into K code blocks {Bi}.

Each block has fixed size MxN pixels.

Each block is independently compressed.

All compressed blocks {Ci}, with compressed sizes {Pi}, are stored in a linear buffer *B*, of size K * M, where M is a fixed size greater than all sizes Pi.

Now, I would like to pack buffer *B* into buffer *C*, and get rid of empty space at the end of each compressed code block Ci.

So, I need a kernel that will:

- for each block Ci, find sum of all Pk for k < i, (call this offset_i)
- copy data for each Ci, from *B* into *C*, at offset_i, of size Pi

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It would probably help a lot if you wrote down an independent (and completely specified) description of what you want an algorithm to do, rather than having the description be entwined with where the data came from.

Comment: This is called *stream compaction* if you want to search for it. It is a very often used primitive in parallel algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, Momotapa! It helps a lot to have a name for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I need to write a **stream compaction** algorithm.

This will require two kernels:

**Kernel 1**: all-prefix-sum algorithm (also called scan) to calculate the buffer offsets: [Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).

The library [clpp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/clpp/) has scan algorithms written in OpenCL, which is my target GPGPU language.

**Kernel 2**: each work group does coalesced reads from input buffer and writes to output buffer, using offsets calculated in Kernel 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet, which (I suppose) does stream compaction. It contains tons of arithmetic, but can be parallelized to desired measure.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Block {
    int size;
    int buf[8];
} Block;

typedef struct BlockPos {
    int t_size; //Temporary size for compaction
    int f_size; //Actual size
    int pos;    //Position
} BlockPos;

int main()
{
    const int num_blocks = 16;
    Block blocks[num_blocks];
    BlockPos pos[num_blocks];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++) {
        //Every block has non-zero length, that's easier
        blocks[i].size = rand() % 7 + 1;

        printf("Block %d len %d:\t", i, blocks[i].size);
        for(int j=0; j<blocks[i].size; j++){
            //Just to make print easier
            blocks[i].buf[j] = rand() % 33;
            printf("%d, ", blocks[i].buf[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<num_blocks; i++){
        pos[i].f_size = blocks[i].size;
        pos[i].t_size = pos[i].f_size;
        pos[i].pos = 0;
    }

    int step = 2;
    /* At every step we reduce number of blocks, being processed, two times.
     * This loop can't be done in parallel. */
    for (int count = 1; count < num_blocks; count *= 2) {

        /* All odd-numbered blocks are compacting to nearest left-side neighbour.
         * This loop can be done in parallel. */
        for (int i = count; i < num_blocks; i += step) {
            int dif = pos[i].pos;
            pos[i].pos = pos[i - count].pos + pos[i - count].t_size;
            pos[i - count].t_size += pos[i].t_size;
            dif -= pos[i].pos;

            // "Replace" previously compacted blocks
            for (int j = i+1; count > 1 && j < i+count; j++) {
                pos[j].pos = pos[j-1].pos + pos[j-1].f_size;
            }
        }
        step *= 2;
    }

    printf("\nPos,\tLen:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<num_blocks; i++){
        printf("%d,\t%d\n", pos[i].pos, pos[i].f_size);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Inner loop (line 54) may be implemented as OpenCL kernel until number of processed elements is big enough. After this you will have array of structures, each element will show where to place compacted block. It can be done then in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as follows:
You have a collection of compressed buffers,  each having a different length.

And finally you want one simple megabuffer without empty spaces. Why not simply store all your buffers in one single block like this 
-first write the number N  of buffers as long value 
- second store a long value array of length N  having the size of each of your buffers 
- and finally write your N buffers

I don't see why you need a kernel for this

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Of course I could do what you suggest, but this is a very serial way of doing things; I am interested in it being fast. So, make use massively parallel GPU to speed things up.

Comment: The most "expensive" task in your algorithm should be the copying of your buffer data. Of course graphic memory is quite fast (DDR5 compared to DDR3), but I can't realize why one should copy the data to the opencl memory before.

Comment: The data is already on the gpu; I am trying to reduce the amount of data I need to transfer back to host over PCI bus

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to the sizes of your Pis.
I would use a temporary buffer where it's length is the total number of blocks.
When you compress a block, you store the length of your compressed block into this temporary buffer.
Then your latest kernel could use this temporary buffer to compute at which address it must write to the final buffer.
For performance reason, you could copy this temporary buffer into the local memory (in the last kernel).